# Automated Mobile Flex Application Testing

Tags: android, apache-flex, automated-tests

I have a flex application that has been built for use on iOS and Android devices.
I've seen an automation tool called MonkeyTalk, which is used for testing mobile applications on emulators or real devices.
I've also seen an automation tool called FlexMonkey, which is used for testing Flex applications.
Has anybody tried using MonkeyTalk to test a Flex application?
Does FlexMonkey have the ability to connect to a mobile device?

a

Comment: Hello. At the end, were you able to perform automated testing for Flex mobile apps?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to perform automated testing for Flex mobile apps.

Comment: Really? That's a bummer. What did you do to perform testing?

Answer (score 0):

From the MonkeyTalk FAQ (circa Dec' 2012)

(http://www.gorillalogic.com/book/monkeytalk-faq)

Q: Can I test desktop apps? Windows Phone 7? BlackBerry? Flex Mobile?

A: No, as of MonkeyTalk Beta5 we support agents for iOS, Android, Flex (**but not Flex Mobile**), desktop web browsers (Firefox only in Beta5), and mobile web. That being said, we hope to add more agents in the future.